# How to append list of child property using Entity Framework and REST Web API

Tags: entity-framework, rest, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I have a `Customer` class:

```
public class Customer : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

And an `Order` class:

```
 public class Order : BaseEntity
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int TotalAmount { get; set; }
}
```

My `CustomerController` has a POST method that takes a `Customer` object and `Put` method to update a single customer.

```
// PUT: api/Customers/5
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PutCustomer([FromRoute] int id, [FromBody] Customer customer)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    if (id != customer.Id)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    _context.Entry(customer).State = EntityState.Modified;

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return NoContent();
}
```

When the customer is initially created there are no orders.

How should I append orders to an existing `Customer` entity?

```
{
"Id": 2,
"Name": "Raas Masood",
"Age": 33,
"orders": [
    {
        "Date": "2/2/2002",
        "TotalAmount": 123
    }
]}
```

Note : This is considering Code First Approach.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a new property (CustomerId) on the class Order, and send the list of orders with that Id.

Comment: But that’s against design first approach . Behind the scenes order table have custId

Comment: Not necessarily; another thing that you can do is look for the customer, and add every new order to Orders property.